# Why the value of "count" is showig 1 instead of 2?

Tags: c#, equals

In my below code I was trying to find the number of words that are in between "-", so I used string.Equals(), but it is not working. And just incrementing the value of "count" in the print section.

```
static void Main() 
{
    int count=0, i;
    string inputString = "Anupam-Datta";
    Console.WriteLine(inputString.Length);
    for(i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
    {
        if(inputString[i].Equals("-"))
            count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of words: {0}", ++count);
}
```

Comment: **This is seeking debugging help but needs more information**; `but it is not working` isn't a question. Please update your post.

Comment: A `string` is nothing but an array of `char`. So you surely want to compare to `'-'`, not `"-"`. Or in other words: `"-"` is not equal to `'-'`.

Comment: `if(inputString[i] == '-')) count++`

Comment: I think the cause of  your problem is that you have `++count` in your `Console.WriteLine` statement.  That will increment the value before printing it.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  The requirement _find the number of words that are in between "-"_ to me would mean "Anupam-Datta" should be zero as there is no second "-" for words to be between.  Or maybe you mean the number of words where a word is defined as characters separated by a "-"?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That does not explain why it prints 1 instead of 2. It just explains why it even prints one instead of zero.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Yes, I agree.  I misread the question.  I thought the goal was to count the number of hyphens in the string.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check a single **character** - that is what `inputString[i]` actually returns - you have to compare it to another `char`, not to a `string`.

Ths use the follwoing instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(inputString.Length);
for(i=0; i<inputString.Length; i++){
    if(inputString[i] == '-')
        count++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Number of words: {0}", count++);
```

Alternativly this smart one-liner:

```
var count = inputString.Count(x => x == '-') + 1;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?  The question is why does it display 2 instead of 1 when printing the count.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway because you can´t compare a `char` to `string`? That´s pretty much what I said in my first sentence.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I was actually trying another program of similar type and I understood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the number of words, which are separated by the char "-", try this:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    string s = "Anupam-Datta";
    int count = s.Split('-').Count();
    Console.WriteLine($"Numer of words: {count}.");
}
```